# Repeating HTML blocks in Django

Tags: django

Not sure what technical term it is I'm looking for, but I have a set of HTML elements that are repeated and wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

Very simplified HTML, if I have the following:

```
<div class='container'>
{{ django.dataFromORM }}
</div>
```

I need to add to `base.html` in a certain section

```
<div id='main-container'>
all elements go here
</div>
```

So on run, I want to add the generated HTML the `main-container`. I've done this before by building in JS, but wondering if there is a way to smoothly do this in Django?

I looked at templates and partials, but not sure that's the proper way or not?

Comment: Django templates can use a For loop as long as you generate an iterable in the view definition.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: Are you repeating database objects or just plain HTML?

Comment: I'm repeating just the HTML based on user selection. I have an AJAX call that pulls the data from the ORM and then build the HTML to inject into UI.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `include` in template to include your repeated html file.

ie

`<div id='main-container'>
  {% include "container.html" %}
</div>`

if you want to repeat it several times you can add it inside a for loop

eg:

`{% for element in elements %} 
  {% include "container.html" %}
{% endfor %}`